# How to make blockquote responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I have the following code:

```css
.blockquote1 {
  padding: 60px 80px 40px;
  width: 1090px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blockquote1 h7 {
  font-family: "Utopia-italic";
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blockquote1:before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  top: 100;
  content: "\f10d";
  font-size: 200px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.blockquote1::after {
  content: "";
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0563bb;
  height: 3px;
  width: 200px;
}

blockquote2 cite {
color: #999999;
position: relative;
font-size: 14px;
left: 845px;
bottom: 60px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
 
blockquote2 cite:before {
content: "\2014 \2009";
}
blockquote {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: italic;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0.25em 0;
padding: 0.35em 40px;
line-height: 1.45;
position: relative;
color: #383838;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  blockquote {
    width: 800px;
  }
}

blockquote:before {
display: block;
padding-left: 10px;
content: "\201C";
font-size: 80px;
position: absolute;
left: -20px;
top: -20px;
color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
color: #999999;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
}
 
blockquote cite:before {
content: "\2014 \2009";
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="blockquote1">
  <h7>Move in silence, only speak when it’s time to say checkmate.</h7>
</blockquote>
<br />
<blockquote2>
  <cite>Kr. Pankaj Yadav</cite>
</blockquote2>
```

So The actual text is responsive like it changes width when device width is changed. However, the `bockquote2 cite` is not responsive and that does not change its position/width on smaller screen sizes. How would I make it so it displays like the big text on smaller devices?

### Expected Output

[image]

This should be the expected output, any suggestions on how to make it possible?

Comment: why do you use a blockqute2 madeup element instead a class like for the first one ?

Comment: Well. You have it all :) custom elements like `blockquote2` (?), font-weight in pixels ( ? ), positioning without units `    top: 100;` (?), you use class then tag for the same element ? it's very confusing.  then you have `left: 845px;` on your cite element. Of course it won't be responsive. Take a look at ' responsive design ' and see what solutions you have.

Comment: Blockquotes *are* responsive, until you tell them not to be.  If you want a responsive layout, break yourself of the habit of setting fixed pixel sizes and using position:absolute.

Comment: `blockquote2` is invalid HTML unless you have code adding it to the `CustomElementRegistry`.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't attribute a run-on sentence to that person. :0

Comment: @MihaiT, what percentages should I use?

Comment: @Spectric, do you have a solution?

Comment: Not related to your responsiveness problem, but probably worth sorting out at the same time is the use of HTML tags. Worth reading up about how they should be used at [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite and [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/html/element/blockquote Amongst other things this will aid accessibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how to place the citation in the right place - justified to the right under the quote. It does not want the whole thing to be responsive (in the sense of altering text sizes etc so that the quote fits into a line the same way as it would on a wider device).

My suggestion would be to use the HTML blockquote and its related cite element together as intended (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite)). That is, the cite is a child of the (main) blockquote. This will also aid accessibility.

So, as a first pass 'quick fix' this snippet alters the HTML to remove the second blockquote as, semantically, there isn't a second quote, and places the citation text aligned to the right. It also alters the setting of the blockquote width as the given settings could make the quote overflow to the right on narrower viewports. It keeps the max width of the quote to 1090px though as in the question's code.

```css
.blockquote1  {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 60px 80px 40px;
  max-width: 1090px;
  width: 100%;
  /* make sure it can fit into its container */
  text-align: center;
}

.blockquote1 h7 {
  font-family: "Utopia-italic";
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blockquote1:before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  top: 100;
  content: "\f10d";
  font-size: 200px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.blockquote1::after {
  content: "";
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0563bb;
  height: 3px;
  width: 200px;
}
blockquote2 {
  rtext-align: right;
  background-color: cyan;
}
.blockquote1 cite {
  color: #999999;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: right; /* added */
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.blockquote1 cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \2009";
}

blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.35em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  color: #383838;
}
/* removed as it would cause overflow on narrower devices
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  blockquote {
    width: 800px;
  }
}
*/
blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \2009";
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="blockquote1">
  <h7>Move in silence, only speak when it’s time to say checkmate.</h7>
  <br>
  <cite>Kr. Pankaj Yadav</cite>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use % and not pixels if you want it to resize with the screen, if thats what you want. Just change where it is top, bottom, left and right from pixels(px) to percentages(%). That should do the trick.

Edit: you also change the font from pixels to %

```css
.blockquote1 {
  padding: 60px 80px 40px;
  width: 1090px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blockquote1 h7 {
  font-family: "Utopia-italic";
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blockquote1:before {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  top: 100;
  content: "\f10d";
  font-size: 200px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.blockquote1::after {
  content: "";
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0563bb;
  height: 3px;
  width: 200px;
}

blockquote2 cite {
color: #999999;
position: relative;
font-size: 10%;
left: 845px;
bottom: 60px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
 
blockquote2 cite:before {
content: "\2014 \2009";
}
blockquote {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: italic;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0.25em 0;
padding: 0.35em 40px;
line-height: 1.45;
position: relative;
color: #383838;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  blockquote {
    width: 800px;
  }
}

blockquote:before {
display: block;
padding-left: 10px;
content: "\201C";
font-size: 80px;
position: absolute;
left: -20px;
top: -20px;
color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
color: #999999;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
margin-top: 5px;
}
 
blockquote cite:before {
content: "\2014 \2009";
}
```

Comment: You should copy down the snippet and make the changes you describe to demonstrate your solution.

Comment: Well, you have to use any relative unit of measure, of which percent is one. You could use `em`, `rem`, `vw`, `vh`, etc., as listed [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#relative_length_units).

Answer (score -1):

1. **Incorrect HTML Tags**

**`blockquote2`** and **`h7`** are not a correct HTML tags.
header tags end in `h6` and you can only use `blockquote`.

2. **You Can Use Media Queries**

As you selected `blockquote` in the following code you can change others as well.

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  blockquote {
    width: 800px;
  }
  .blockquote2 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
}
```

3. **Wrong Sizing Used For Fonts**

You can only use `% px em rem vw ...`. just don't use *width*.